# Объясните поведение Observable RxJava

Tags: java, android, map, rxjava

Этот код:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
          .map(x -> x * 2)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(observer);
```

Выводит в лог 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 (т.е. `onNext` отрабатывает 5 раз). Если же применить map(`x -> 123`)

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
          .map(x -> 123)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(observer);
```

то в логи 123 пишется только два раза. Почему так?

upd.:Выключение из цепочки потоков на ситуацию не влияет.

Comment: Должно работать одинаково для 1 и второго варианта. Возможно у вас InstantRun сбоит. Попробуйте его отключить

Comment: после выполнения данного кода, приложение случаем не закрывается? Может он просто не успевает вывести?

Comment: Догадывался, что так быть не должно. InstantRun отключен.

Comment: @Komdosh, нет, приложение не закрывается.

Comment: ну отписки тоже не происходят?

Comment: @Komdosh, если имеются в виду какие-то отписки моими руками - нет. Для двух кусков в посте код абсолютно одинаковый. Observer просто пишет логи в onNext, другого кода в приложении вообще нет.

Comment: Ну я понимаю, что одинаковый, но такое впечатление, что это просто проблема многопоточности из-за контроля файла лога, попробуйте приостановить поток Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: @Komdosh, нет, не сработало. Приостановил на 5 секунд - результат не изменился. Такое поведение и на эмуляторе и на "живом" устройстве.

Comment: а в логах случаем нет такой строки `identical 3 lines`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логгер скрывает одинаковые строки, поэтому вывод выглядит следующим образом:

```
123
(com.example.app) identical 3 lines
123
```

Comment: OMG, даже стыдно стало :/ Просто на лог стоит TAG и строки identical не видно. Благодарю!